# How can I add a tableViewCell inside another TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

the problem here is that I've got a component thats a cell, and I want to include it in a tableview with some other icons and labels in the cell. Maybe the best solution here would be to include a tableview inside of the cells, with a unique cell in it. I've tried to do it and it worked but when it came to launch another screen when selecting the cell it only worked on the margin where the inside tableview isn't included, how could this be solved? [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMkPz.png) Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need the "unique cell" to be a `UITableViewCell`? Maybe just a regular `UIView` will do better?

Comment: Please add code so that we know how far have you done or where you stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

Change the isUserInteractionEnabled property of the inner table view to **false**.